# My website doesn't open in Facebook in-app browser

Tags: html, wordpress, facebook, facebook-graph-api, wordpress-theming

I have a Facebook Page and I have a website based on WordPress. I share links from my website to the Facebook page, but unfortunately, when I used the Facebook app on my mobile, the links do not open in Facebook in-app browser.

What should I do to solve this problem? Another link from another website is working correctly, but from my website, it's not opening.

Comment: "How to open a link wit hthe facebook app" is not a programming question. Facebook has it's own algorithm for deciding which items are worth precaching / likely to be opened

Comment: How to determine the algorithm or adapt according to algorithm so that the website opens in the inapp browser?

Answer (score 1):

This may or may not help, but try running your website though the [Facebook debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/). You might also hit the Scrape Again button while you are there. Then see if your page open in the in-app browser.